# variable not set to using angular 2

Tags: angular

Two-way data binding does not work correctly.

Can I recover the data using {user | json}, but when using [(ngModel)] = "user.username" an error is displayed.

Interface

```
export interface UserModel {

        username?: any;
        email?: any;
        first_name: any;
        last_name: any;
        profile: ProfileModel;

}

interface ProfileModel {

        nome_empresa: any;
        cnpj: any;
}
```

componente

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PerfilService } from './perfil.service';
import { UserModel } from './user.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'mw-perfil',
  templateUrl: './perfil.component.html'
})
export class PerfilComponent implements OnInit {


  user: UserModel = new UserModel();

  constructor(private perfil: PerfilService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.perfil.get().subscribe((perfil) => {
      this.user = perfil;

    })

  }

}
```

Template

```
<input id="username" class="form-control" data-error="Usuário inválido" placeholder="" required="required" type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="user.username">
```

> PerfilComponent.html:31 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'username' of undefined
>       at Object.View_PerfilComponent_0._co [as updateDirectives] (PerfilComponent.html:31)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13058)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12238)
>       at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12603)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12535)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12244)
>       at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12603)
>       at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12561)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12239)
>       at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12603)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `user` by an asynchronous way. The data won't be ready even though you invoke the asynchronous call at `ngOnInit`.

Since your are using `user.username` at `ngModel`, the `safe navigator operator` can not be used here. So the only solution is initializing `user` first, below ways will solve the problem:

```
  // option1
  user: UserModel = new UserModel();

  // option2
  constructor(private perfil: PerfilService) { 
    this.user = new UserModel();
  }

  // option3
  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = new UserModel();
    this.perfil.get().subscribe((perfil) => {
      this.user = perfil;

    })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Is this the best way to load bank data into a form or is there a better way?

Comment: perfil.component.ts (11,25): 'UserModel' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: @user2716095 AFAIK, these are the only ways. And I recommend you using the option1.

Comment: Did not work. 
perfil.component.ts (11,25): 'UserModel' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: @user2716095 can you post what you have changed right now?  and see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11807

Comment: @user2716095 sorry for late response. I haven't been using interface for a while.  You can try initialize it like this `this.user = {};`

Comment: Does not work. perfil.component.ts (16,5): Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'UserModel'.
  Property 'username' is missing in type '{}'.

Comment: it worked like that -> user = <UserModel>{} --- But the ProfileModel interface is still undefined.

Comment: @user2716095 I would recommend you to change `interface` to `class`(with constructor to initialize inside fields).